# Authenticate Identity Provider Google with Cognito - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-signin, federated-identity

I'm having issues finding documentation or examples on how to authenticate a google user without amplify on the backend by getting request code from google callback redirectUri like this

```
    // google callback redirect uri express route

    router.get('/google/callback', function(req, res, next) {

    const { code } = req.query as string;
    const { tokens } = await googleAuthClient.getToken(req.query.code);
    const idToken = tokens.id_token;

    const ticket = await googleClient.verifyIdToken({
        idToken: idToken,
        audience: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID 
    });
    const payload = ticket.getPayload();
    const userid = payload['sub'];
```

and use that userId or idToken or whatever is needed to authenticate with a Cognito User Pool App Client. Currently I have a button on the frontend that sends me to google signin where I can click my gmail and then it sends a redirect to my expressjs backend google redirectUri endpoint where I have the code above in. I've been trying different AUTH FLOWS for cognito using initiateAuth and setting AUTH_FLOW in the params. but I haven't had much luck in authenticating using CognitoIdentityServiceProvider from aws-sdk. I don't now which AUTH_FLOW I would use and what would be the password for instance since the user logged in via google and not form password passed to frontend. Is there a better way?

I see mentions of amplify, but my understanding is it's for the frontend. I want to be able to authenticate without using amplify on frontend that hits cognito hosted UI and instead get authorized from backend.

My question is how can I take what I have in code above when I click

```
login with google > 
click my email > 
sends redirect uri
```

with code in req.query and then from there authenticate with cognito and get accessToken. I already have the account created and linked

[image]

so unless this is wrong, I just need to authenticated the user already linked. I assume there's an AUTH_FLOW I can use, but not sure what params values it would need or which AUTH_FLOW to use. I appreciate any help!

Comment: I've done this before using `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider`'s `adminInitiateAuth` with auth flow `ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH`. You'll need to pass the username and password to this call as well. More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminInitiateAuth.html

Comment: I'm logging in via the google redirectUri so user never entered a username and password into a form. I might be wrong, but wouldn't I have to reset their password to a temporary password if I'm coming from google redirectUrl to pass it to params since they didn't login via form. That wouldn't be ideal if so.

Comment: It's not exactly answering your question, but if you had API-G in front of your backend, you could add your Cognito User Pool as authorizer to API-G, and it would handle the entire auth flow for you.

Comment: I'm using serverless framework with lambda. I believe this deploys behind api gateway on sls deploy.

Comment: My guess is: you want to set up an IdP within AWS which points to Google for the authentication.  I'm not sure what happens after that for you but, next guess, you have a token and can proceed in the same way as a cognito auth.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create.html